# SimpleXML - assigning variable of type SimpleXML to child Element?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to 'overwrite' a child with a SimpleXMLElement variable.

My XML is

```
<data>
  <ch>
    <nest>plzoverwritekthx</nest>
  </ch>
</data>
```

My PHP attempt is:

```
$DATA=(new SimpleXMLElement("<data><ch><nest>plzoverwritekthx</nest></ch></data>"));
$DATA->children()[0]->children()[0]=(new SimpleXMLElement("<dragon>x</dragon>"));
exit($DATA->asXML())
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data><ch><dragon>x</dragon></ch></data>
```

Actual output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data><ch>x</ch></data>
```

Can I prevent the new node from being cast to a string?

Comment: Edit now includes the XML twice...

Comment: Yes. One time in indented and well-formed form and another time included in your PHP code as string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class SimpleXMLElement doesn't have a `replaceChild()` or `overrideChild()` method. So the solution would be:

- First delete the node, `<nest>plzoverwritekthx</nest>` from the XML document.
- And then use `addChild()` method of SimpleXMLElement class to add appropriate node, `<dragon>x</dragon>`

So your code should be like this:

```
$data=<<<XML
<data>
  <ch>
    <nest>plzoverwritekthx</nest>
  </ch>
</data>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

// Remove node: <nest>plzoverwritekthx</nest>
unset($xml->children()[0]->children()[0]);

// Add node: <dragon>x</dragon>
$xml->children()[0]->addChild('dragon', 'x');

// display
exit($xml->asXML());
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data><ch><dragon>x</dragon></ch></data>
```